# Open a valid url in VIM , with file browser?

Tags: vim

I wanted to open a URL with `xdg-open` when the cursor was staying on some string that points to a valid `folder`
   By pressing some key , it will launch `xdg-open the_valid_url` for example.

Is that possible ?

And i hope it works even a `space` resides in the local url.

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with next mapping:

```
:noremap ,o :!xdg-open <cfile><CR>
```

And now, inside `vim` put cursor over your string and press `,o` in normal mode. In my computer (linux) uses `dolphin` to open local folders and `konqueror` to open urls.

---

**EDIT**:

To open files with spaces, add the space character to option `isfname` (32 is the decimal number of the space character):

```
:set isfname+=32
```

and use this different map:

```
:noremap ,o :execute ":!xdg-open " . shellescape( '<cfile>' )<CR>
```

Comment: It's not working when space is present , e.g /tmp/Folder A/path , but i'll mark this as the best answer for now , thanks !

Comment: @warl0ck: Added the option to open files with spaces.

Comment: @Birei: This only works if `<cfile>` is a full path. What would I have to do if vim should interpret `<cfile>` as relative to the directory which contains the currently open file?

Comment: @andreas-h: It works for me. In what case doesn't work for you? Can you provide an example?

Comment: 2020 and still relevant